# TYPO3: TCA How to add UID to new table as Parent UID

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript, typo3-tca

I want to create a new content type(Ads), I have created a Ad container  in the `tt_content` table as `CType` = '`ad_container`', Now i need to put the ads in this container. So I wish to create a new table `tx_adcontent`. Each ad container contains multiple ads, and my confusion is that for the front-end rendering I have some other codes to fetch these ad parameters and show in a particular template structure.

So to fetch that ads from the particular uid of the current pid, i need a refrence in my new table `tx_adcontent` as parent_uid, other wise I can't put that ads in respective container.(each page contains multiple ad container. )

Finaly My Intention is to put `parent_uid` in the new table `tx_adcontent`. How do I do this with `TCA`, How do I configure in TCA. Otherwise I need to enter that `parent_uid` into a text field manualy, is there any automatic field inserting possible there? (I dont want to show that id in my backend edit form, but need to insert that automatically to db table(`tx_adcontent`))

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The description of your table structure and the relations is not very understandable. Maybe a schema would help. You may google for `tcedefaults` or `flexforms` or `hooks`. I did not really understood your problem correctly, so help is pretty vague right now...

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Extension Kickstarter](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/kickstarter) for creating own extension which will allow you to

- create new column in existing table
- create new table for your records
- create a new `ContentType` and some basic PHP class

etc. Most important is that will create proper SQL schema AND tca configuration of it for your own table , it will contain also `pid` field by default. It will store the UID of the page where the record is created.

If you don't want to begin your work from the scratch extension you can just carefully examine the created elements and copy/paste the things that you need to your current solution.

Although it's longer way there is no easier way to getting started with extension development.

Comment: i need a parent_uid field. That parent_uid contains the uid of the tt_content table. so in my table there are more contents belongs to that parent_uid. like Sub Element of the tt_content